# Fix file endcoding when downloading a file from Linux to Windows in php

Tags: php, linux, text, encoding, character-encoding

Ok I have an issue.  I have a Linux web server (RHEL 4 with apache 2) that is used to house an application.  Part of this application is a set of php scripts.  I created a script that accepts some form variables and then downloads a file to the user.  Here si the code:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$destFileName);
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fullPath));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($fullPath);
```

This all works fine, and the file gets downloaded.  But there is a problem.  These files are being downloaded from the Linux box, to a Windows machine (ALWAYS).  The problem is the encoding.  When you look at the file on the Linux box all the text is aligned and all the columns look fine.  (The files are just flat text files).  But when the file gets downloaded onto the Windows box, and opened in Notepad, the file is all fouled up, and nothing is aligned.  You also see weird charactors (the ones that look like a box, but that is just the generic representation for the unknow charactor).  When this file is imported into another program, it does not work.

However, when I open the file up in WordPad, all the text look correct.  If I save it from wordpad it will import correctly, and look correct in Notpad.

I don't have much knowlege on file encoding, so any information on how I can encode the file before sending to the user for download would be great.

I did try replacing the  `readfile($fullPath);` with:

```
$handle = @fopen($fullPath, "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $buffer = fgets($handle);
        $buffer = str_replace('\n', '\r\n', $buffer);
        echo $buffer;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just in case anybody comes here with similar problems: if line breaks turn into boxes in Notepad/Editor but look fine in Wordpad, it's a matter of not using Windows linebreaks (for some reason Notepad is pretty anal about linebreaks whereas Wordpad gets it right). If it's other characters that look off, you're probably dealing with an encoding problem (e.g. UTF-8 treated as Windows-1252 or US-ASCII).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an issue with the following line:

```
$buffer = str_replace('\n', '\r\n', $buffer);
```

You'd need to use double quotes there. "\n" is newline. '\n' is the literal char sequence backslash-n:

```
# php -r "var_dump('\n', \"\n\");"
string(2) "\n"
string(1) "
"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a Unix utility 'unix2dos' and 'dos2unix' that might help.  You could call it from php as a system call.

Or, I'm sure there is a php version of the same thing.

But I'm not a php guy.

Comment: I like this idea, being is that it probably does more than just update the newline to the DOS format.  The problem is, is when I try and execute it from php, I get no response.  Any one have any help.

Comment: Ah, you'd have to have it modify files for you.

  sys('unix2dos',$fullPath,$fullPath."_dos")

And then send the _dos file.
And then delete it after.

Not ideal.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: I did not know that about PHP quoting.  Still, you may need to decide on a standard encoding when multiple languages will be used, the rest of this post is still valid.

Windows generally uses ANSI or ASCII encoded files for text, using the character set that is local to the system. (Like cp1252).

It might be easiest just to encode it all in UTF8, and then tell notepad to read the file in as a UTF8 document. (It is a drop-down in the File->Open dialog.)

I do not see a way to specify the encoding from the command-line, and I am not sure that notepad will find it automatically.